# Sorting Vectors Of Shared Pointers in C++

Tags: c++, sorting, c++11, vector, shared-ptr

Let's say we have a simple class as such:

```
class Data {
private:
   std::string m_name;
   unsigned m_id;

   Data( const std::string& name, unsigned id ) :
   m_name( name ), m_id( id ) {}

   void setName( const std::string& name ) { m_name = name; }
   void setId( unsigned id ) { m_id = id; }

   std::string getName() const { return m_name; }
   unsigned    getId() const { return m_id; }
}; // Data
```

Now Let's say we have another class that populates and manages these in a container of smart pointer that are read in from a file.

**Database.h**

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H

class Data; 

class Database {
private:
    std::string m_filename;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Data>> m_vpData;

public:
    explicit Database( const std::string& filename );        

    void displayByOption( unsigned option = 0 );

private:
    void parseFile();
    void display() const;

    // Sorting Methods Used for std::sort
    bool sortByName( const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d2 );
    bool sortById( const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d2 );

}; // Database

#endif // DATABASE_H
```

I'm not having any issues with the opening, reading and parsing of the file data. What I am struggling with is the methods to be passed into std::sort.
These are the display methods within Database.cpp that would be of concern.

Note: I do have `<algorithm>` & `<functional>` included in my standard header along with the other appropriate stl headers.

**Database.cpp**

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// display() - Shouldn't be an issue, but here for reference
void Database::display() const {
    for ( unsigned u = 0; u < m_vpData.size(); u++ ) {
        std::cout << m_vpData[u]->getName() << "/t"
                  << m_vpData[u]->getId() << "/t" << std::endl;
     } 
} // display

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// displayByOption() - This function itself isn't an issue
// But the std::sort method is generating a compiler error
void Database::displayByOption( unsigned option ) {
    switch( option ) {
        case 1: { // Sort By Name
             std::sort( m_vpData.begin(), m_vpData.end(), sortByName );
             display();
             break;
         }
         case 2: { // Sort By Id
             std::sort( m_vpData.being(), m_vpData.end(), sortById );
             display();
             break;
         } 
         default : { // Unsorted - Order Read In By File
             display();
         }
     }
} // displayByOption

// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// sortByName()
bool Database::sortByName( const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d2 ) {
     return d1->getName() < d2->getName();
 } // sortByName

 // ------------------------------------------------------------------------
 // sortById()
 bool Database::sortById( const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d2 ) {
     return d1->getId() < d2->getId();
 } // sortById
```

Here is the Compiler Error that was generated

```
1>------ Build started: Project: FileParse, Configuration: Debug Win32 ------
1>  CharacterDatabase.cpp
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\fileparse\fileparse\characterdatabase.cpp(66): error C3867: 'CharacterDatabase::sortByName': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\fileparse\fileparse\characterdatabase.cpp(66): error C2672: 'std::sort': no matching overloaded function found
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\fileparse\fileparse\characterdatabase.cpp(66): error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm(3209): note: see declaration of 'std::sort'
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\fileparse\fileparse\characterdatabase.cpp(71): error C3867: 'CharacterDatabase::sortByHealth': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\fileparse\fileparse\characterdatabase.cpp(71): error C2672: 'std::sort': no matching overloaded function found
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\fileparse\fileparse\characterdatabase.cpp(71): error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm(3209): note: see declaration of 'std::sort'
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\fileparse\fileparse\characterdatabase.cpp(76): error C3867: 'CharacterDatabase::sortByExperience': non-standard syntax; use '&' to create a pointer to member
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\fileparse\fileparse\characterdatabase.cpp(76): error C2672: 'std::sort': no matching overloaded function found
1>c:\users\skilz80\documents\visual studio 2015\projects\fileparse\fileparse\characterdatabase.cpp(76): error C2780: 'void std::sort(_RanIt,_RanIt)': expects 2 arguments - 3 provided
1>  c:\program files (x86)\microsoft visual studio 14.0\vc\include\algorithm(3209): note: see declaration of 'std::sort'
========== Build: 0 succeeded, 1 failed, 0 up-to-date, 0 skipped ==========
```

I'm usually decent in figuring out compiler errors but this one has me stumped. I've done basic sorting methods like this with basic class types that are directly stored into the container, but this is my first time trying to do it where a shared pointer of that object is stored in the vector.

What I'm not sure about is a few things.

- Is it valid to have these sort methods to be passed into std::sort within a class? - I do not see why this should be a problem.
- Do I need to have the parameters for the sort function to be passed to std::sort as the objects themselves or the smart pointer of them? It would make sense to pass the smart pointer since this is what is stored in the vector since we are working with the iterators begin() and end().

Any thoughts would be extremely helpful!

What is causing this file to not compile and to generate the error messages provided? The only difference is the class name between what I have posted and what I have in my editor. Also, what would be the simplest and most effective way to sort a `vector<shared_ptr<Object>>` that is a member of a class object?

Comment: You cannot pass non-static member functions as the predicate in std::sort without using `bind` trickery.  Just make the functions static member functions, or use lambdas.

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie yeah; I just posted an answer to my own question.The irony here is about 2-5 minutes after posting my question I happened to find a valid solution. I was searching for hours before I posted my question here.

Comment: @Francis Cugler I found some other compiler errors in the code and edited (but unfortunately the reviewer didn't accept the change). Can you please update the code

1- In function displayByOption() under case 2 a typo "m_vpData.being()" instead of "m_vpData.begin()"
2- In file Data.h set/get must be public

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is that you cannot simply pass non-static member functions as part of the `std::sort` predicate.

The simplest solution, given your code now, is to make `Database::sortyByName` and `Database::sortById` `static` member functions.

```
static bool sortByName( const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d2 );

static bool sortById( const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d2 );
```

---

Note that there are various other solutions, such as using [boost::bind](http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/develop/libs/bind/doc/html/bind.html), function objects / functors, and with C++11, lambdas.  I won't go over them, but just to give you other options.

Comment: Yes thank you. As I did mention in my answer I was getting that writer block syndrome! It happens from time to time. Yet just by forgetting about the functions not being static passed to the predicate of std::sort MVSV compiler errors are too vague and cryptic about this error, lol. Eventhough I answered my own question; I will accept your answer for the prompt and timely response.

Answer (score 1):

You cannot use **non-static member** functions in std::sort(), please make your function **non-member** functions or make them **static members**(as you have already figured this out). The implementation of the code with non-member sort functions.

### Database.h

```
#ifndef DATABASE_H
#define DATABASE_H

#include "Data.h"

class Data;

class Database
{
private:
    std::string m_filename;
    std::vector<std::shared_ptr<Data>> m_vpData;

public:
    explicit Database(const std::string& filename);

    void displayByOption(unsigned option = 0);

private:
    void parseFile();
    void display() const;

    // Sorting Methods Used for std::sort


}; // Database

bool sortByName(const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d2);
bool sortById(const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d2);

#endif // DATABASE_H
```

Non member sort functions implementaiton (Notice removal of *Database::*)

```
// -------------------------------------------------------------------------
// sortByName()
bool sortByName(const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d2)
{
    return d1->getName() < d2->getName();
} // sortByName

// ------------------------------------------------------------------------
// sortById()
bool sortById(const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d1, const std::shared_ptr<Data>& d2)
{
    return d1->getId() < d2->getId();
} // sortById
```

An [example](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/algorithm/sort/) how to use std::sort

Answer (score 0):

Irony at its best, I've been searching online for hours for a proper resolution to my problem, so I decided to ask the community here. While waiting for an answer, not long after, I found a possible solution to my problem. As for now, I am able to compile and build the solution, but I have not yet tested it to see if it works as expected. Here is what I've found to resolve my compiling issues.

I changed the 3 sorting functions declarations & definitions within my database class from the previous signature above to the following:

```
static bool sortBy ( std::shared_ptr<Data> d1, std::shared_ptr<Data> d2 );
```

and I moved them from the private section to the public section. I made the functions both public and static, I removed the const reference from the parameters. Now my source file compiles and I am able to build with 0 errors. Now it is just a matter of time to test out my class.

**Edit**

After reading a comment from a community member from my question above, I think that the major issue was the functions not being static. So now that I have the static storage for the method calls; I'll try to see if I can add the const reference back to the function signatures.